# Checking code change background image with over link with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, background-color

I have this code. 
The idea is that when the mouse is on hover the link the background-image of a div changes and when is not, shows the original image. I´ll do it with 5 links but at the moment I can´t make it works even whit one.

**SCRIPT JQUERY**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#changebg").hover(
    function() {
        //mouse over
        $('.thediv').css('background-image', 'url("www.site.com/img/img2.png")');
    }, function() {
        //mouse out
        $('.thediv').css('background-image', 'url("www.site.com/img/img1.png")');
    });
});
</script>
```

**CSS STYLE**

```
.thediv { position: relative; background-image:url('www.site.com/img/img1.png'); }
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="thediv">

<div style="position: absolute;">
<a href="#" class="linkstyle" id="changebg">CHANGE</a>
</div>



</div>
```

And an extra... To make the same but with 5 link...
EX:

```
<a href="#" class="linkstyle" id="changebg">CHANGE</a>
<a href="#" class="linkstyle" id="changebg1">CHANGE</a>
<a href="#" class="linkstyle" id="changebg2">CHANGE</a>
```

...

I have to copy and paste the same code or is there a better form to do it?

Thanks a lot :D

Have a great start of week.

Comment: The problem might be related to the fact that `div.thediv` has no height or width. The absolutely positioned child is removed from the document flow, so its parent collapses and the background image never shows. Is that the problem you're having?

Comment: Well... I think so! I need to respect both positions for the design so I cant change them. But yes... When I put the mouse over the LINK I get NO IMAGE on the DIV and when I quit it, still the same. Thanks for your time :D

Comment: I think it may help to describe your context. What are you aiming to accomplish? Will all the links look the same and will each one change in the same way when you hover over it? Or are they going to be something like thumbnail images, with a different image for each one? Is there a reason not to just use CSS for this?

Comment: Is .thediv allowed to have a height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a height and width on .theDiv like so:

```
.thediv { 
    position: relative; background-image:url('http://fpoimg.com/300x250'); 
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
}
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/46LdLbpb/) is a working example. Also your example images didn't work (they dont actually exist as far as I can tell) so I changed them to some filler images so you could see that my example works

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `:hover`

```css
.thediv {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/50/50/cats');
  top: 0px;
}
a[id^="changebg"]:hover {
  color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/50/50/technics');
  z-Index: 1;
  top: 0px;
  transition: top 1ms linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="thediv">
  <div style="position: absolute;">
    <a href="#" class="linkstyle" id="changebg">CHANGE</a>
    <a href="#" class="linkstyle" id="changebg1">CHANGE</a>
    <a href="#" class="linkstyle" id="changebg2">CHANGE</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe he wants `.thediv`'s background to change while hovering the link. So this won't work until we get parent selectors. Edit: Unless of course he can do as you and cover the entire div with the link. But what's the point in all the divs to begin with if that is the case?